# Explanation for different Noise Signatures on Series Terminated Clock Line

Tags: noise, clock, termination, ringing

In the picture below (taken from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fCfZoI7-7Y)), it is explained what the clock signal would look like depending upon the value of Driver and Series Resistance value compared to the transmission line impedance.

The video explains what the clock would look in each of the cases. I am trying to understand WHY?

Clearly, I am learning Transmission lines so any pointers or help would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Find a different source for your information - that picture is just plainly wrong and confusing. For a start the term Zo is usually reserved for the characteristic impedance of the cable yet it seems to be part of the driving source (the triangle at the left). Next the scale of the middle picture and the right hand picture are vastly wrong compared to each other. The end of the cable appears to be terminated in a capacitor but it's value (and therefore significance to the picture) is not mentioned. Neither are the non-ideal voltages "noise signatures" - they are the effects of reflections.

Comment: This question is very broad, and would require an extensive answer based on your current level of understanding. So I'm closing it as a duplicate of a previous question that asked for a non-mathematical explanation of transmission lines in general, which has links to additional information.